# Porting Windows Phone 8.1 app to Windows Phone 8.0

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

Yes, I know, it sounds a bit silly, but due to some specific requirements I need to do that...

I am deploying a project in Visual Studio 2013 Express which targets to Windows Phone 8.1 and what I would like to do is retarget it to Win Phone 8.0 in order to be able to build my app to Windows Phone 8.0. Can I achieve that in some subtle way or should I create new Windows Phone 8.0 project and copy-paste whole code there..?

Comment: This may not be possible if you use features specific to WP 8.1

Comment: And for doing that you'd need Visual Studio 2012 express for Windows Phone 8.0

Comment: I don't use features specific for WP 8.1, I just installed wrong VS, mainly because I am an iOS developer and got used to easily setting up OS requirements via IDE - in XCode it is one parameter in project's configuration file. Ah, that Microsoft logic... P.S. Thanks for answers

Comment: Is your project a Windows Phone 8.1 Runtime or Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight project?

Comment: It is a Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight project.